# Максимальный белый прямоугольник

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Один из моих знакомых, дает очень интересные задачи на собеседованиях. Некоторые из которых, мне очень интересно решать. Вот одна из таких.

Дано прямоугольное поле из черных и белых клеток в произвольном порядке. Белым прямоугольником называется прямоугольная область, которая содержит только белые клетки. Максимальным белым прямоугольником называется любой белый прямоугольник максимальной площади.

1. Предложите алгоритм, который находит максимальный белый прямоугольник.
2. Сколько времени он работает? Можно ли быстрее?
3. Приведите оценку снизу для сложности алгоритма.

В рамках форума, предлагаю обсудить алгоритм решения задачи. На вход имеем двумерный массив типа char. Белая позиция - это пробел, черная - любой другой символ.

Comment: Ох уж эти олимпиадные задачки…

Comment: Насколько я помню, эта решается довольно несложным динамическим алгоритмом. Была пару лет назад на ИОИП вроде…

Comment: Если подсказывать, задача становится не интересной :). Посмотрим, кто решит первый.

Comment: А как мы узнаем, что это кто-то решил сам, а не нагуглил? ;) Задача-то известная и древняя аки мир, думаю, в интернете решений навалом.

Comment: Никак. Кому интересно, как мне, тот решит ее сам.

Comment: Вопрос: являются ли прямоугольниками прямоугольники с смежными белыми клетками. Например как в кресте или букве Г?

Comment: Нет, это другая задача :) .

Comment: Давайте лучше поищем максимальный черный квадрат :)) может тоже попадем в историю как Малевич.

Comment: «Являются ли прямоугольниками прямоугольники с смежными белыми клетками?» — охрененный вопрос, я выпал в осадок о_0. Являются ли правильным треугольником два равных правильных треугольника, составленные сторонами так, что образуют ромб?

Comment: Когда-то пробовал решать эту задачу, но за O(h*w) не придумал. Нашел решение за O(h,w) тут: [нахождение наибольшей нулевой подматрицы](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/maximum_zero_submatrix). Прикольная динамика ;)

Answer (score 3):

Придумалось вот такое вот решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

// Включает левую верхнюю точку, исключает правую нижнюю
struct Rect
{
    Rect() :
        x1(0), y1(0), x2(0), y2(0)
    {}
    Rect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) :
        x1(x1), y1(y1), x2(x2), y2(y2)
    {}
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
};

Rect solve(const char** field, int width, int height)
{
    struct Local_
    {
        Rect answerRect;
        int answer;
        int y;
        int* up;

        void tryRect(int l, int r)
        {
            int minv = *std::min_element(up + l, up + r);
            if (minv * (r - l) > answer)
            {
                answer = minv * (r - l);
                answerRect = Rect(l, y - minv + 1, r, y + 1);
            }
            for (int i = 0, k = -1; 2 * i - (k + 1) / 2 < r - l;
                 i += (1 - k) / 2, k *= -1) // порядок ...6420135...
            {
                int x = (r - l) / 2 + k * i;
                if (up[x] == minv)
                {
                    if (x > l)
                        tryRect(l, x);
                    if (x + 1 < r)
                        tryRect(x + 1, r);
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
    } local;

    local.answer = 0;
    local.up = new int[width];
    std::fill_n(local.up, width, 0);
    int& y = local.y;
    for (y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            if (field[x][y] == ' ')
                ++local.up[x];
            else
                local.up[x] = 0;
        }
        local.tryRect(0, width);
    }
    delete [] local.up;
    return local.answerRect;
}
```

Время работы на поле h*w в худщем случае O(h^2 * w), хотя на случайном вводе будет работать очень быстро: O(h * log(h) * w). В качестве улучшения можно транспонировать ввод, если h > w, что позволяет добиться O(min(h, w)^2 * max(h, w)). Зато используется только O(w + h) дополнительной памяти :)

Если говорить об оценке снизу, то я сомневаюсь в существовании решения за O(h * w), потому что для каждой клетки приходится перебирать omega(1) прямоугольников-кандидатов и выбирать среди них максимум по площади. Возможно, кандидатов даже Theta(min(h, w)), хотя доказать эту оценку я не могу.

Comment: вот теперь я понимаю преимущество uml диаграмм

Comment: Ого! А UML-то тут каким боком? )))

Comment: Мне кажется я умею решать ее за O(h*w). Никто не подскажет где эта задача есть на online-judge чтобы проверить?

Comment: @winger Если не жалко, решение в студию!

Comment: Так никто и не решил за O(h*w) ?

Answer (score 1):

***NB** решение подробно расписано тут: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/maximum_zero_submatrix.*

Задачу можно решить за *O(nm)*, где *n* - высота поля, *m* - ширина. Это оптимальное время. Алгоритм инкрементальный, использует память *O(m)* - хранится информация только о последней строке поля.

Идеи две. Первая - сканируем поле по строкам. Обновляем массив высот - сколько пустых клеток в данном столбце:

[image: массив высот]

В каждой строке мы получаем функцию, в подграфик которой нужно вписать прямоугольник максимальной площади. Это можно сделать за *O(m)* - двигаемся слева направо, поддерживаем набор кандидатов в максимальные прямоугольники с правым нижним углом в текущей точке:

[image: кандидаты в максимальные прямоугольники]

Кандидаты, вернее их левые верхние углы, хранятся в стеке. Когда прямоугольник удаляется из стека, его площадь обновляет текущий максимум площади.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

class MaxWhiteRect {
public:
    MaxWhiteRect() : heights(), max_area_(0) {}

    void update(const std::string &row) {
        if (heights.size() <= row.size()) {
            heights.resize(row.size() + 1, 0);
        }

        for (size_t j = 0; j < row.size(); ++j) {
            if (row[j] == ' ') {
                ++heights[j];
            } else {
                heights[j] = 0;
            }
        }

        std::stack<std::pair<int, int>> s;
        s.push(std::make_pair(0, 0));

        for (size_t j = 0; j < heights.size(); ++j) {
            const int h = heights[j];
            int left = j;
            while (s.top().second > h) {
                left = s.top().first;
                update_max_area(left, j, s.top().second);
                s.pop();
            }

            if (s.top().second < h) {
                s.push(std::make_pair(left, h));
            }
        }
    }

    int max_area() const {
        return max_area_;
    }
private:
    void update_max_area(int left, int right, int height) {
        max_area_ = std::max(max_area_, (right - left) * height);
    }

    std::vector<int> heights;
    int max_area_;
};

int main() {
    MaxWhiteRect mwr;
    std::string s;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
        mwr.update(s);
    }
    std::cout << mwr.max_area() << '\n';
}
```